# Why am I getting undefined value for size of the Set?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have got this inside one of functions,

```
this.personService.getPersonInfo(this.personId).subscribe((res => {
        let response = res.body;
        let num = response.personList.size;
        ...
    }))
```

This is what response object is supposed to look like,

```
export class Person {
  personExists: boolean,
  personList: Set<Address> = new Set<Address>();
}
```

For some reason, value of size of the personList I get is `undefined`, even though I can clearly see the data during debugging.

This is what the data looks like during debugging,

```
response = {
  personExists = true,
  personList = Array(1)[Object]
  -> 0 = Object{id: 1, name: Tony}
     length = 1
}
```

Comment: Arrays have a _length_, not a size. You can literally see that property in what you've posted.

Comment: But if I write length instead of size then I get an error "Property length does not exist on type Set". I don't understand where array is coming from even though I have defined it as set.

Comment: I'd guess you're lying to the type system somewhere. If this is coming from JSON (e.g. via HttpClient) then note sets do not exist in JSON.

Comment: You should correctly set the types of the data returned by your API. Your API does not return a Set, so don't type it as such.

Comment: This is what I have in my DTO which API is returning, `Set<PersonDTO> personList = new HashSet<>():`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whilst you have typed it as a set, deserializing the JSON will result in an array. TypeScript types aren't used whatsoever during deserialization - they are only at compile time for type checking.

You should use `.length` instead.

Comment: length is not working for me. It's throwing an error.

Comment: @cs55 could you paste the error here?

Comment: You have to change the type of the field personList in the Person class from Set to Array. And one more thing: there is no point in using a class here, it's actually dangerous. Make person an interface or a type.